# The correct approach to change the MUI Drawer content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm completely new on React and I'm trying to understand what is the best approach to make a simple transition of body content using React + MUI + Drawer.

The code below is completed wrong and summed up, only for example propose:

```js
return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Drawer>
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['Users', 'Messages'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <PersonIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Main open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader />
        
        <Users /> <!-- ********* HERE ********* -->

      </Main>
    </Box>
  );
```

Supposing that I have a menu with Users and Messages items and I also have `<Users />` and `<Messages />` components. I want to change the `<Users />` for `<Messages />` when the user clicks on the Message Menu Item.

I initially implemented that transition using visibility true or false, that implementation doesn't require routes changes, obviously. So, when the dashboard loads and show up the content the route keeps `/dashboard`.

But I'm not confident that is the best approach.

- What would it be the best approach? Routes?
- What about the performance issues involved?
- In the future I want to show up a User form in the same place, I would use the same approach?

Comment: It depends on what routing library you're using, this is done by changing the state of the component. Do you use nextjs or react router?

Comment: I'm using the react router

Comment: Instead of the line `<Users /> <!-- ********* HERE ********* -->`, you should use the `<Outlet />` component by react router. let me know if you need a full example

Comment: I just read about the Outlet component. It looks like the Outlet will "read" the URL(route) and load the correct component, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using react-router-dom, this is basically done by using the `<Outlet />` component.

Here's a simple example:

```
// # AppRouter.jsx
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import HomePage from '@/pages/HomePage'
import UsersPage from '@/pages/UsersPage'
import MessagesPage from '@/pages/MessagesPage'

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<DashboardLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<HomePage />}/>
      <Route path="/users" element={<UsersPage />}/>
      <Route path="/messages" element={<MessagesPage />}/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```
// # DashboardLayout.jsx
import { Outlet, matchPath, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const { pathname } = useLocation()
const amISelected = (path) => matchPath(pathname, path)

<Stack direction="row">
  <Drawer open>
    <List>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemButton selected={amISelected("/")} component={Link} to="/">
           <ListItemText>Home</ListItemText>
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemButton selected={amISelected("/users")} component={Link} to="/users">
           <ListItemText>Users</ListItemText>
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemButton selected={amISelected("/messages")} component={Link} to="/messages">
           <ListItemText>Messages</ListItemText>
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
     </List>
  </Drawer>
  <Main>
    <DrawerHeader /> {/* to allocate the top margin of the topbar */}
    <Outlet /> {/*  HERE */}
  </Main>
</Stack>
```

Here's a [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/mui-drawer-example-twfy48?file=%2Fsrc%2Flayouts%2FDashboardLayout.tsx%3A52%2C18) for an example: